# "connection reset by peer" when connecting to Cloud Run using net/rpc

Tags: go, google-cloud-run

I have an built two services in Go using `net/rpc` - one client and one server. The server implements a Ping service that returns a pong message. I have successfully set up the rpc server by registering the Ping service, handling http and creating a tcp listener. Calling the server locally from a local client works and I receive the pong message from the Ping service.

I deploy the server to Cloud Run with HTTP/2 enabled. I update my local client to use the provisioned url as address along with port `443`. I then receive the following error:

```
 dial-http tcp ***.a.run.app:443: read tcp ***:57000->***:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

The cloud logs show nothing, suggesting that the error appears in an earlier layer, some kind of reverse proxy that Google uses infront of Cloud Run maybe? My understanding was that Cloud Run could handle RPC, but I cannot get it to work. Any Ideas on why?

Comment: This error occurs when an application has an established TCP connection with a peer across the network and that peer unexpectedly closes the connection.check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#connection-reset-by-peer) on how to resolve